Split a dataframe based on the rows content
I have the following dataframe:
    import pandas as pd
data = {'Name': ['Ankit', 'Amit', 'Aishwarya',
                 'Priyanka','Kovacs','Tompos'],
        'Age': [21, 19, 20, 18, 20, 19],
        'Stream': ['Math', 'Commerce', 'Arts',
                   'Biology', 'Math', 'Arts'],
        'Percentage': [88, 92, 95, 70, 80, 83]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'Age', 'Stream',
                                 'Percentage'])


    Name    Age Stream  Percentage
0   Ankit   21  Math    88
1   Amit    19  Commerce    92
2   Aishwarya   20  Arts    95
3   Priyanka    18  Biology 70
4   Kovacs  20  Math    80
5   Tompos  19  Arts    83

I would like to split the dataframe based on rows that contain Arts ins Stream column in the following way: the rows between the two rows that containing the Arts form a separate dataframe.
My code is the following:
first=df.iloc[0:2]
second=df.iloc[3:5] 

But I would like to replace this with a code that takes into account if the index changes, applicable to larger dataframes and. Can someone help me with this?
Thanks!

Please don't use images of data, provide a [mre]. Most likely you want to split using groupby, combined with cut. IF this is not what you want, make sure to provide a reproducible example and the matching expected output.
